# IE7 floats disappear when their parent is position:relative

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, css-float, css-position

This is a pared down version of a problem I am facing with IE7.  In all other (newer) browsers, this displays fine... why does `position:relative;` have an effect on `float: right;` or `float: left;`?  Is there a way to keep the `position: relative` without sacrificing the functionality of `float`?

JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uW7JV/2/

Without `position: relative;`
[image]

With `position: relative;` (on the red box)
[image]

Even more trimmed-down version: http://jsfiddle.net/uW7JV/4/

Interesting... Removing the `<div class="clearboth"></div>` allows the content to show.  However, I do need that functionality there, so I'm still looking for a fix.  http://jsfiddle.net/uW7JV/9/

Comment: do you really need that relative:position ? Since IE7 behave more alike IE6 (i think this the worse one) , i guess you should set inside floatting tag as well in relative position. position:relative makes a reflow/refresh on screen, so the parent is redrawn and not the childs there wich are not really in the flow ... floatting. (hope you understand my meaning)

Comment: In this example, it is not relevant, but I do need it for the site that I am creating.  There are more than just the floated elements inside that parent.

Comment: okay, keep playing under IE7 or 6 in standard mode with relative positioning and see what i mean by reflow at screen. If you where used to code for IE6/7, you might remenber some content that would disseapear with hasloyout or not where relative was the cure to keep elements drawn on screen.
You are dealing with the famous haslayout there :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `overflow: hidden` to `.column-wrapper` so that it wraps its floating children. You won't need the `.clearboth` div and CSS at all after you do this.

The other issue you need to solve is column widths, since `box-sizing: border-box` is not supported in IE7, you need to account for your padding when assigning `width`.

```
div {
    padding: 5px 1%;
}
.column-wrapper {
    background: orange;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.main {
    background: yellow;
    float: right;
    width: 64.6%;
}
.sidebar {
    float: left;
    background: green;
    width: 31.3%;
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/myajouri/uW7JV/15/

Another way to go about this is to use the [Clearfix hack](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/)

```
.clearfix {
  zoom: 1; /* for IE6/7 */
}

.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

Then add the `clearfix` class to `.column-wrapper`.

Comment: Yup, I'm aware of the box sizing issue.  That was just for the demo's sake.  `overflow:hidden;` isn't ideal as I need to have things "overhanging" the floated columns.

Comment: In that case use `zoom: 1` to trigger `hasLayout` on `.column-wrapper`. I recommend using the Clearfix hack. I will update my answer .

Comment: sigh. why did I not think of `zoom:1`... that's like IE 101.  I kept the code as-is, and just added it to the div with `position:relative;`.  magic.  thank you!